# Can't submit app to the App Store because the Archive button in Xcode is grayed out

Tags: ios, xcode

I cannot archive my Xcode project and submit it to the App Store. The **Archive** button in Xcode is grayed-out.

[image]

I have a valid iOS Distribution Certificate in my Keychain and also created an App ID as well as a Distribution Provisioning Profile in the iOS Development Member Center.

[image]

I also checked Apple's troubleshooting guide for this issue, but their only suggestion hints to the **Build** section in the **Scheme**, where there is a checkbox to activate/deactivate the **Archive** functionality. However, that checkbox is checked in my case.

[image]

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've got an actual device selected rather than the simulator (or select *Generic iOS Device*)!

#### This will work:

[image]

#### This won't:

[image]